# Generic DataFlavor for All MIME-Types As InputStream

Tags: java, clipboard

I'd like to read the clipboard in a console-application and print out the contents of the clipboard. That should happen completely independent of the MIME-type. As far as I can tell in Java it's all done based on the data's MIME-type and I should know what I expect. The default `DataFlavor`s only support text and some binary stuff.

Anyway, I want to cover images, all kinds of text, serialised stuff and any kind of binary data.

The easy part is

```
Clipboard systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
```

Looping over `systemClipboard.getContents(null).getTransferDataFlavors()` doesn't help much. I also tried to create my own `DataFlavor`, but that doesn't work (from what I analysed in Java's source the sub-type can be "*"):

```
systemClipboard.getData(new DataFlavor("application/*", "bytes"))
```

Also I don't know how to figure out what the MIME-type actually is. No UNIX-tool I looked at could tell me that.

My final goal is to write a data generator that does the opposite, meaning create the clipboard data and provide that to the application in question. But, for now I have to figure out the structure I need to create then, which is why I need that parser first.

Comment: The "Content" of the clipboard can be DataFlavor dependent. For instance, think about when you copy the text from a Word file or a WebPage into notepad (ie plain text). Yes, you get the same letters, but you lose all the styling = two different sets of data returned

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is invalid: The contents (data) returned by the Clipboard depends on the DataFlavor requested.

Comment: @ControlAltDel That's right. And I want to see what MIME-type that is in there and its binary presentation, in your case what it looks like for Word or in HTML. In other words I want to understand the flavour it is in. And I want to build the `DataFlavor` for it.

Comment: Did you try [systemClipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html#getAvailableDataFlavors--)?

Comment: @VGR Yes, and for the case I want to examine the array is empty. The return value of `getContents()` is a `sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable`, i.e. not null. Its `getTransferDataFlavors()` also returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

After deep-diving into the involved objects with Reflection I came up with this. I know that this usually is bad and it actually uses undocumented methods in undocumented classes, which means that this might not work with the next Java-release. Due to that I'm still looking for a nice solution! **Don't hesitate to post an answer if you have one!**

Anyway:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Clipboard systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
  System.out.println("systemClipboard: " + systemClipboard.getClass().getName());

  Method method = systemClipboard.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getClipboardFormats");
  method.setAccessible(true);
  long[] clipboardFormats = (long[]) method.invoke(systemClipboard);

  for (long clipboardFormat : clipboardFormats) {
    String line = "format " + clipboardFormat + ": ";

    try {
      method = systemClipboard.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getClipboardData", long.class);
      method.setAccessible(true);
      byte[] bytes = (byte[]) method.invoke(systemClipboard, clipboardFormat);

      line += "length: " + bytes.length + "\n";
      line += DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes) + "\n";
      line += new String(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
      e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stringWriter));
      line += stringWriter.getBuffer();
    }

    System.out.println(line);
  }
```

}

For the clipboard I looked at I noticed that it actually contains plain readable XML. However, it's not possible to load that the normal way using the `DataFlavor`s available. I assume that this is due to a possibly missing MIME-type information in the clipboard.

Note that for my system the second line prints out `systemClipboard: sun.awt.X11.XClipboard` and the two methods I use are `protected`. I'm trying to say that it may look different on anyone else's machine.

*As an additional information who want to use the above code:*

The clipboard formats I run in are 589 (the only one that works), 460, 462, 463, 464. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx) 589 (= 0x024D) is a private clipboard format.

What would be interesting to see is where Java maps that `clipboardFormat` to a MIME-type. Maybe that would explain a few things.

Comment: I would just poll for known DataFlavors:  all the non-deprecated public static fields of DataFlavor, plus DataFlavor.getTextPlainUnicodeFlavor().  It certainly is not a nice solution, but at least it doesn’t use undocumented APIs and will work reliably.